# Capturing audio using Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, capture, audio-recording

I have some `AudioSink` which is assigned to some `CaptureSource`.

```
CaptureSource captureSource = new CaptureSource() {
    VideoCaptureDevice = null,
    AudioCaptureDevice = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultAudioCaptureDevice()
};
SampleAudioSink audioSink = new SampleAudioSink() {
    CaptureSource = captureSource
};
captureSource.Start();
```

The `AudioSink` implementation simply logs the called function to see that it works properly. However, the `OnSamples` method stops being called after 37 samples.

- OnCaptureStarted
- OnFormatChange
- OnSamples (1)
- OnSamples (2)
- OnSamples (3)
- [...]
- OnSamples (35)
- OnSamples (36)
- OnSamples (37)

`OnCaptureStopped` is never called; the `CaptureSource` should continuously call this function. The `CaptureSource` also does not invoke the `CaptureFailed` event.

What could produce this strange behaviour and what attempts could I take to fix it?

**I have uploaded a complete source code which produces the problem to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ghB1ATM3)**

Comment: What is the `State` of the `CaptureSource` at the 36th and 37th call? Did it change?

Comment: `State` == `Started` for all calls. Also, there is an event handler attached to `CaptureFailed` which is never called.

Comment: I read that, I just wanted to make sure we weren't dealing with a bug here that prevented it from raising the event :)

Comment: Now I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` when trying to read the state from the 37th call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the garbage collector deleted the `AudioSink` after 18 seconds...
Adding the `AudioSink` as a class member solved the problem.

```
[...]
TextBox log;
SampleAudioSink audioSink; // to prevent garbage collector from collection
private void Application_Startup (object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
    [...]
}
[...]
```